# Java 14 invalid CEN header (bad compression method: 9) with Windows 10 zip flles

Tags: java, windows, zip

I'm trying use Java's ZipFile to get information from zip files generated by windows 10, and this works for smaller zip files < 300MB but for larger I am getting

```
    IOException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad compression method: 9)
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad compression method: 9)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1502)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1465)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1209)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1172)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:167)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:138)
```

The zip files are not corrupt, under RHEL 7 I can unzip them with the unzip command. I've tried both OpenJDK 14.0.1 and Oracle JDK 14.0.2 and am getting the same error.  Any thoughts? Is it just that windows modified their zip algorithm and Java has not caught up?

Comment: *FYI:* Compression method 9 is `Deflate64`

Comment: Did you find what's causing the problem/did you fix it?